# What is the equivalent of collection.save() in PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

The mongo shell has the [db.collection.save()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/method/db.collection.save/#db-collection-save) command, which can be used to replace an existing document.

What is the equivalent in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're looking for [`MongoDB\Collection::updateOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-updateOne/#phpmethod.MongoDB%5CCollection::updateOne) in the PHP MongoDB library.**

However, you need the `upsert` option to set to `true` which would emulate the "update if exists, create if it doesn't" behaviour of `db.collection.save()`.

Some sample code from [MongoDB's PHP Library Manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/tutorial/crud/#upsert) (great resource):

```
<?php

$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->test->users;
$collection->drop();

$updateResult = $collection->updateOne(
    ['name' => 'Bob'],
    ['$set' => ['state' => 'ny']],
    ['upsert' => true]
);

printf("Matched %d document(s)\n", $updateResult->getMatchedCount());
printf("Modified %d document(s)\n", $updateResult->getModifiedCount());
printf("Upserted %d document(s)\n", $updateResult->getUpsertedCount());

$upsertedDocument = $collection->findOne([
    '_id' => $updateResult->getUpsertedId(),
]);

var_dump($upsertedDocument);
```

Output:

```
Matched 0 document(s)
Modified 0 document(s)
Upserted 1 document(s)
object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#16 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
  array(3) {
    ["_id"]=>
    object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId)#15 (1) {
      ["oid"]=>
      string(24) "57509c4406d7241dad86e7c3"
    }
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "Bob"
    ["state"]=>
    string(2) "ny"
  }
}
```